# Partitioning a compact and totally disconnected space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a **compact**, Hausdorff, totally disconnected space, i.e. a compact space that has a basis consisting of clopen subsets. Let also $F\subset C(X)$ be finite and $\varepsilon>0$. I am trying to show that there exist disjoint, clopen subsets $X_1,\dots, X_r$ such that $X=\cup_{j=1}^rX_j$ and such that for each $j=1,\dots,r$ there exists a point $x_j\in X$ so that $|f(x)-f(x_j)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in X_j$ and all $f\in F$.

I am not sure on how to do this. On the one hand, we may set $U_x=\{y\in X: |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon \text{ for all }f\in F\}$. Obviously $U_x$ are open and $X=\cup_{x\in X}U_x$, so by compactness we may reduce the cover to a finite subcover. But then I do not know how to bring into play the total disconnectedness. On the other hand, starting from total disconnectedness, I can write $X$ as a finite, disjoint union of clopen subsets. But then I do not know how prove the existence of these magical points. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your sets $U_x$; since $X$ is zero-dimensional, $U_x$ contains a clopen nbhd of $x$, so you might as well assume that the sets $U_x$ themselves are clopen. Now take a finite subcover $\{U_1,\ldots,U_n\}$ and refine it to a disjoint clopen cover of $X$: let $V_1=U_1$, $V_2=U_2\setminus V_1$, $V_3=U_3\setminus(V_1\cup V_2)$, and so on.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks! Would you mind (briefly) explaining why totally disconnected spaces are also called zero dimensional?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: They aren’t in general, but locally compact Hausdorff spaces are totally disconnected iff they are zero-dimensional. In general zero-dimensionality — having a base of clopen sets — is stronger than total disconnectedness. You’re welcome!